# testcafe log full request header

Tags: node.js, http, xmlhttprequest, automated-tests, testcafe

For a test case, I want to log the full request and/or response header of a testcafe test with the RequestLogger. 
Is this possible? By default, only some basic information is logged.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to enable the [necessary options](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html#creating-a-logger) that are disabled by default when you create a request logger:

[image: testcafe request logger options]

If any information is missing, specify what it is and why you need it.